# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, type-conversion

I am trying to convert `DateTime?` to `DateTime` but I get this Error:

> Error 7   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to
> 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists

Here is my code:

```
public string ConvertToPersianToShow(DateTime?  datetime)
{
  DateTime dt;
  string date;
  dt = datetime;
    
  string year = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetYear(dt));
  string month = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt));
  string day = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(dt));
    
  if (month.Length == 1)
  {
     month = "0" + Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt));
  }
  if (day.Length == 1)
  {
     day = "0" + Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(dt));
  }

  //date = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetYear(dt)) + "/" + 
  Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt)) + "/" +
  //Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(dt));
  date = year + "/" + month + "/" + day+"("+dt.Hour+":"+dt.Minute+")";

  return date;
}
```

Comment: This is your problem:  dt = datetime; You should check if the datetime has value (HasValue) and then try to get it, or act accordingly if the value is not there.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1) Get default value

```
dt = datetime??DateTime.Now;
```

it will assign `DateTime.Now` (or any other value which you want) if `datetime` is null

2) Check if datetime contains value and if not return empty string

```
if(!datetime.HasValue) return "";
dt = datetime.Value;
```

3) Change signature of method to

```
public string ConvertToPersianToShow(DateTime  datetime)
```

It's all because `DateTime?` means it's nullable `DateTime` so before assigning it to `DateTime` you need to check if it contains value and only then assign.

Comment: I don't think ?? works here. Datetime on the left still can't be converted. I think you have to do datetime.HasValue ? datetime.Value : DateTime.Now

Comment: @MillieSmith nope, `??` means it, exactly `datetime.HasValue ? datetime.Value : DateTime.Now` it's just short version of that

Comment: I know that. I just don't remember the compiler figuring that out (even though it should be able to).

Comment: `??` works like a charm but we are using current date as the default. what is i want to assign, for example, 1.1.2000 as default date?

Comment: @Cromwell use `dt = datetime??new DateTime(2000,1,1);`

Answer (score 30):

`dt` is `nullable` you need to access its `Value`

```
if (datetime.HasValue)
    dt = datetime.Value;
```

It is important to remember that it can be `NULL`. That is why the `nullable`struct has the `HasValue` property that tells you if it is `NULL` or not.

You can also use the [`null-coalescing operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173224.aspx) `??` to assign a default value

```
dt = datetime ?? DateTime.Now;
```

This will assign the value on the right if the value on the left is `NULL`

Comment: I changed it some thing like that :DateTime dt=DateTime.Now;

Comment: @EhsanAkbar maybe change it to `DateTime dt = datetime??DateTime.Now`?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my answer. That way you get to keep your value if there is one

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are passing a [nullable type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) to a non-nullable type.

You can do any of the following solution:

A. Declare your `dt` as nullable

`DateTime? dt = dateTime;`

B. Use `Value` property of the the `DateTime? datetime`

`DateTime dt = datetime.Value;`

C. Cast it

`DateTime dt = (DateTime) datetime;`

Answer (score 3):

you should be using the .Value of the datetime parameter.
All Nullable structs have a value property which returns the concrete type of the object. but you must check to see if it is null beforehand otherwise you will get a runtime error.

i.e:

```
datetime.Value
```

but check to see if it has a value first!

```
if (datetime.HasValue)
{
   // work with datetime.Value
}
```