# Bootstrap Datepicker: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-datepicker

I am a newbie here. I have gone through similar questions here but none of them helped. I have the following in my `ViewModel`:

```
public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
```

When I run the code, in the `View` after `GET Method`, I am getting the default dates as: `01/01/0001`, in other words, `null`/default value. I searched online and found out that I need to make these fields `nullable`. Therefore, I changed the above code to:

```
public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }

public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
```

Upon changing, I am getting the following error for both `FromDate` and `ToDate`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What to do?

**Edit:**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Locate(...)
{
    InventoryHistory history = new InventoryHistory();
    ...
    ...
    history.FromDate = locationsViewModel.FromDate;
    history.ToDate = locationsViewModel.ToDate;
    ...
    ...
    _context.Add(history);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Details");
}
```

Comment: Where is the error occuring? How are you mapping the view model to the data model? (and as a side note a value of `01/01/0001` is not a `null`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, this should help. See edit

Comment: The code you have shown does not generate that error. Where is it occurring? (and delete you pointless `name` and `id` attributes in the inputs - they are already created for you - and in any case you should never set the `name` attribute when using a TagHelper)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, since we have found the correct solution, could you post it so that I can mark it as correct? This will be helpful for others who might have the same/similar issue in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972965/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-datetime-to-system-datetime-an-expli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your data model has non-nullable properties for `FromDate` and `ToDate`, but the view model has equivalent nullable properties.

You cannot explicitely convert a `DateTime?` to a `DateTime` because the value may be `null`.

If your view model properties are decorated with the `[Required]` attribute and you have checked `ModelState.Isvalid` before mapping (i.e. you know the property has a value), then you can use

```
history.FromDate = locationsViewModel.FromDate.Value;
```

If not, then the property could be `null`, in which case you need to use

```
history.FromDate = locationsViewModel.FromDate.GetValueOrDefault();
```

which will set the data model value to `1/1/0001` (the default value fro `DateTime`)