# Finding Max Date using Entity Framework Core - in Razor Pages

Tags: entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am building a Razor Pages web application that would register a user into an exam.  The `ExamRegistration` Model has a field called `MaxDateForExam` that can be nullable as this is a new feature added to existing database at a later time.  When creating the exam I want to fill this field with a value after the OnPost.

If the user is applying for the exam for the first time, simply get the `ExamDate` and add 1 year.  On subsequent registrations (user failed exam) I do not wish to create a new `MaxDate` but grab the `MaxDate` from the first time registering record.

My ExamRegistrations model has the following property

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? MaxDateForExam { get; set; }
```

On the page where I would register a person into a new exam I need to perform a check:

- If the person is registering the 1st time I would grab the `ExamDate`
  and add a year to it which would then populate a `MaxDateForExam`
  field.
- If the user is registering for an exam which is not a 1st time I need
  to have the app go into the ExamRegistration table and grab the
  existing `MaxDateForExam` a value for the previous registration (if
  one exists).  This is what I have so far.

I am just unable to find the correct code to extract the value of `MaxDateForExam`.  Here is part of my code....

```
public DateTime MaxWriteDate { get; set; }                 
public Models.ExamRegistration ApplicantRecord { get; set; }

if(ExamRegistration.ExamAttempt == "1st Attempt")
     {                    
        MaxWriteDate = ExamRegistration.Exam.ExamDate.AddYears(1);
     }
     else
     {
         ApplicantRecord = _context.ExamRegistrations                        
         .Where(m => m.ApplicantID == ExamRegistration.ApplicantID && m.ExamAttempt == "1st Attempt") 
         .FirstOrDefault();

         if(ApplicantRecord == null)
          {
              MaxWriteDate = ExamRegistration.Exam.ExamDate.AddYears(1);
          }
          else
          {
               MaxWriteDate = ApplicantRecord.MaxDateForExam;   ???????FAILS????????
          }
      }
```

Any direction I can get would be helpful.  The error always seems to revolve around the unable to convert System.DateTime? to System.DateTime. Are you missing a cast.

I have mark an answer as correct and I have learned a bit more of C# and nullable types.  Thanks.

I was able to get past the error by using the code:

```
MaxWriteDate = OldMaxWriteDate.MaxDateForExam ?? DateTime.MinValue;
```

Thanks for the help.

PS.... If I need to mark something else (first time user to the great resource) please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972965/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-datetime-to-system-datetime-an-expli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the value of MaxDateForExam might by null, so you are not allowed to assign it to a variable that is not nullable.  Try this:

```
      if(ApplicantRecord == null)
      {
          MaxWriteDate = ExamRegistration.Exam.ExamDate.AddYears(1);
      }
      else
      {
          if (MaxDateForExam.HasValue)
          {
              MaxWriteDate = ApplicantRecord.MaxDateForExam.Value;
          }
          else
          {
              // Handle case where MaxDateForExam does not have a value
          }
      }
```

See the nullable value types documentation for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types